# How to add an external link to an image?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Want to link the image to external link, I would say it is in a .wrap but can not seem to get to work. I have checked most of the questions  but everything I try does not help.

```
var photos = [
{ file: 'image1.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.googl.com'},
{ file: 'image2.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.bing.com'},
{ file: 'image3.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.yahoo.com' }
];

var photoCount = photos.length;
var pageItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < photoCount; i++) {
    if (photos[i].tag != tag && tag != 'all') {
        continue;
    }
    var img = $('<img></img>')
    .attr('src', 'static/images/tv/' + photos[i].file)
    .addClass('slider-photo');
    pageItems.push({item: img,caption: descDiv});
}
```

Comment: "*... I would say it is in a .wrap but can not seem to get to work...*," can you explain yourself?

Comment: photos[i].tag != tag && tag != 'all' ... All of the items are going to 'continue'

Comment: i think you didnt declared the tag variable..

Comment: $('<img></img>') can/should be $('<img />') ... you still have to append img to the DOM and you can just use .click(function(){...}) instead of wrapping it with an anchor.

Comment: I am new to jquery but from what I have read Image elements can not be links but could be wrapped in anchor elements .wrap

Comment: what is the output of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var photos = [
    { file: 'image1.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.googl.com'},
    { file: 'image2.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.bing.com'},
    { file: 'image3.png', tag: 'search', href: 'http://www.yahoo.com' }
];

$.each(photos,function(k,v){
    $('<img />')
        .attr('src', '../static/images/tv/' + v.file)
        .addClass('slider-photo')
        .append('body')
        .click(function(){
            document.location.href = v.href;
        })
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/npsAz

Comment: note that you won't see images there because they are relative to the root at codepen.io...  replace those with absolute paths and your images should appear and link to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

just add a `<a>` tag around it..

```
 var img = $('<img></img>')
.attr('src', 'static/images/tv/' + photos[i].file)
.addClass('slider-photo');
var finalOutput='<a href="externallink">'+img+'<a>'; //<-----here
pageItems.push({item: finalOutput,caption: descDiv});
```

however.. hope you have some other codes too , that appends the created image in the document..